# ProgressDialog shows after the method is complete

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make a ProgressDialog show up while the application is looking for an IP Address in the network. In my present codes, even though the initialization of the ProgressDialog is at the beginning, it shows after what I am waiting for finishes.

Here is my code:

```
 val clickListener = View.OnClickListener { view ->
        when(view.id) {
            R.id.button_upload -> {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog(activity)
                progressDialog!!.setMessage("Looking for the server. Please wait...")
                progressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
                progressDialog!!.show()
                if(findServer()) {
                   Log.i("TAG", "FOUND")
                } else {
                   Log.i("TAG", "NOT FOUND")
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    private fun findServer(): Boolean {
        if(canPingServer()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "We are connected to the server server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            gView.button_upload.setText("Upload")
            gView.button_upload.isEnabled = true
            progressDialog!!.dismiss()
            return true
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "We cannot connect to the server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            gView.button_upload.setText("Server not found")
            gView.button_upload.isEnabled = false
            progressDialog!!.dismiss()
            return false
        }
    }

private fun canPingServer(): Boolean {
        val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        try {
            val mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 192.168.1.4")
            val mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor()
            Log.i("TAG","mExitValue $mExitValue")
            return mExitValue == 0
        } catch (ignore: InterruptedException) {
            ignore.printStackTrace()
            Log.i("TAG"," Exception:$ignore")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.i("TAG"," Exception:$e")
        }
        return false
    }
```

I believe that I have  to create the `AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>` for this, but the thing is, this fragment have inherited from another class already like so

```
class UploadFragment : BaseFragment() {.....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing because you findServer() function needs to execute on a different thread.

```
 val clickListener = View.OnClickListener { view ->
    when(view.id) {
        R.id.button_upload -> {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog(activity)
            progressDialog!!.setMessage("Looking for the server. Please wait...")
            progressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
            progressDialog!!.show()
            Thread(Runnable {
                if(findServer()) {
                   Log.i("TAG", "FOUND")
                } else {
                   Log.i("TAG", "NOT FOUND")
                }
            }).start()
        }
    }
}
```

AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> is another way to multi thread in java but I believe the way I showed above would suit your needs better. You need to be careful though because anything that has to run on the main thread I.e. your toasts or where you are setting the text of your elements still needs to happen on the main thread. You can accomplish this by surrounding anything that requires being run on the main thread with

```
activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
    //put code here that needs to be run on the ui thread
})
```

In you case an example would be

```
    private fun findServer(): Boolean {
   
    if(canPingServer()) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
            Toast.makeText(context, "We are connected to the server server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            gView.button_upload.setText("Upload")
            gView.button_upload.isEnabled = true
            progressDialog!!.dismiss()
        })
        return true
    } else {
        activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
            Toast.makeText(context, "We cannot connect to the server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            gView.button_upload.setText("Server not found")
            gView.button_upload.isEnabled = false
            progressDialog!!.dismiss()
        })

        return false
    }
}
```